# O que devo fazer em relação a este problema de fala?

Tags: português-europeu

Bom dia, eu ando num curso de programação, e nestes últimos dias têm me feito sofrer bastante. Eu não tenho jeito com Português de Portugal e por isso estou sempre a levar na cabeça... Ao ponto de me ir a baixo... O que quero perguntar é se me podem dizer/explicar o que devo fazer para melhorar:
• A fala
• A escrita
• A apresentação (quando tenho de apresentar projetos)

Basicamente como devo aprender o que eles denominam de Soft Skills visto que sou péssimo em Português de Portugal, e já nem sequer acredito na minha capacidade de Inglês. Preciso de ajuda e já nem sei o que fazer.

Atenção que eu sou Português, falo Português de Portugal mas nunca tive boas notas na escola e neste momento preciso.

Edit---
Eu dou muitos erros esse e o meu problema de escrita e acho que ja perceberam que nao sei usar pontuação.
Em relação a fala as vezes sinto que me falta palavras para me saber expressar melhor.
E a apresentação eu ate tenho jeito mas como falho a falar e a escrever fica mal apresentado...
E mais eu quero saber falar bem... Saber palavras mais complexas aquelas típicas palavras que se dizem palavras de 500€ mas quero saber usar no dia a dia... Quero ter um vocabulário mais rico e sem erros ortográficos logo como e que posso melhorar nestas areas ? Essa e a minha questão eu quero melhorar e nao sei como

Comment: Desculpe a franqueza, mas não entendi exatamente o que está sendo perguntado aqui...

Comment: A pergunta é muito genérica e difícil de responder. Acredito que o grande problema não é a lingua, mas falar com público, apresentar ideias e etc. Não há mágica, tem que praticar, participar de algum grupo que possa treinar esse tipo de atividade.

Comment: João, espero que consigas superar esse problema, mas este não é o site indicado para esse tipo de pergunta--a pergunta é off-topic, na linguagem aqui do site. Aqui nós tratamos de questões concretas de língua portuguesa, como significado de uma expressão, origem de uma palavra ou expressão, maneiras corretas e idiomáticas de exprimir esta ou aquela ideia, etc. >>

Comment: >>Mas deixa-me que te diga, se a tua pergunta é uma bom exemplo da tua escrita, não tá assim tão mau; já vi e ouvi muito pior. Vê lá, talvez possas dizer aos teus críticos para terem paciência, que estás a fazer o que podes, e para serem construtivos.

Comment: O que necessitas fazer amigo, é exercitar a mente. Leia bons livros, comece com temas que goste, ficção, romance etc. Com a leitura você exercitará seu português, sendo ele europeu ou não.

Comment: Primeiro compre uma boa gramática da língua portuguesa.  Leia de ponta a ponta e assimile tudo.  Depois passe a ler livros de escritores portugueses do século XXI.  Leia boas crônicas e textos de bons jornalistas.  E converse bastante com quem sabe falar bem e preste atenção ao que você pode corrigir em você.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez frequentar um curso de oratória facilitasse a apresentação de trabalhos. O problema pode passar pela confiança e não pela língua em si.